# How to insert into a table from another table and from user input?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is something like this

```
INSERT INTO BOOKS(borrower_name,isbn) VALUES("Jane",SELECT isbn from TABLE...);
```

This is wrong obviously. But I am trying to get something that would work the way this would (if it did).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were **very** close

```sql
INSERT INTO books (borrower_name, isbn) 
SELECT 'Jane', isbn 
  FROM table_name
-- WHERE id = ?
```

*You might want to limit number of rows coming from `table_name` by using `WHERE` clause and proper condition(s)*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc28e/1)** demo

---

More over if you meant to return from `SELECT` **only a scalar value** (just one ISBN) then you were **correct** in the first place and could've used syntax showed in your question

```sql
INSERT INTO books (borrower_name,isbn) 
VALUES ('Jane', 
        (
          SELECT isbn 
            FROM table_name
           WHERE id = 1
        ));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88575/1)** demo

Answer (score 2):

What you were doing is also right, u only missed `()` for select statement:

```
INSERT INTO BOOKS(borrower_name,isbn) VALUES("Jane",SELECT isbn from TABLE...);
```

should be modified to:

```
INSERT INTO BOOKS(borrower_name,isbn) VALUES("Jane",(SELECT isbn from TABLE...));
```

and it will work perfectly fine!! here is the [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8fee/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO BOOKS(borrower_name,isbn)  
SELECT 'Jane', isbn from TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Check This My Answer...
 Example:
 I have two table Employee and Client

```
Insert into Employee (name, city) values((select name from client where id=2),'example');
```

follow this method